# How to make Django use current application's templates folder?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Right now I have a Django project with three apps. In my last app, the index.html loaded by my views.py is the index.html in another app's templates folder. Note this is how it is actually loading it, but not how I intend it load. The index.html in templates where the corresponding views.py is defined is not used. What I am wondering is how I define my settings so that the templates folder for the current application directory is used. This is my settings.py with respect to templates:

```
TEMPLATES = [ 
    {   
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },  
]
```

This is the call to index.html

```
def indexView(request):
    form = FriendForm()
    friends = Friend.objects.all()
    return render(request, "index1.html", {"form": form, "friends": friends})
```

Comment: Are your template files in the same directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good practice is that from the inside of your urls.py from your app, you add :

```
app_name = 'your_app_name' # Now, you can call this app from the {% url tag %}
```

And your template structure should contain app directories, and when you want to render to a different template you can use :

```
return render(request, 'myApp1/index.html')
return render(request, 'myApp2/index.html')
```

But remember, in your main templates folder, you need to add 2 directories,

```
templates/myApp1/index.html,
```

and

```
templates/myApp2/index.html
```

And finally, did you added app_name to your apps URLs? And after that try with the first one, or with the full path.

```
{% url 'myApp1:post_friend' %} or full path {% url 'myApp1/index.html' %}
```

Comment: You can mark this as an answer if it solves your problem. Thanks!

Comment: When I do this I get a reverse lookup error for the url in an ajax call in my index.html.

Comment: The url is derived from {% url 'post_friend' %} where post_friend is the name of a url defined in the app's urls.py (not the project's urls.py).

Comment: Did you add app_name to your apps urls? And after that try with {% myApp1:post_friend %}

Comment: And i have to ask, did you included your app urls in your root urlpatterns?

Comment: Please add your urls code in here, since that's where your problem is, and so we can have a clear picture.

Comment: It worked when I used "{%url 'myApp1/post_friend' %}" in my index.html. If you update your answer for the final solution, I'll mark it solved.

Comment: Updated! Glad you found a solution ;)

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer when you can :) Thanks